# How should I insert into Meteor collection using autoform/collection2?

Tags: meteor, meteor-collection2

I'm trying to do the autoform books example using Meteor.  How exactly should I do the Books.insert ?

I see the example:

```
Books.insert({title: "Ulysses", author: "James Joyce"}, function(error, result) {
  //The insert will fail, error will be set,
  //and result will be undefined or false because "copies" is required.
  //
  //The list of errors is available on
  //`error.invalidKeys` or by calling
  Books.simpleSchema().namedContext().invalidKeys()
});
```

I'm not entirely sure how I should hook this up with the rest of my code:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {

   Books = new Meteor.Collection("books");

   var Schemas = {};

  Schemas.Book = new SimpleSchema({

  title: {
   type: String,
   label: "Title",
   max: 200,
   optional: true
  },
  author: {
   type: String,
   label: "Author",
   optional: true
  },
  copies: {
   type: Number,
   label: "Number of copies",
   min: 0,
   optional: true
  },
  lastCheckedOut: {
    type: Date,
    label: "Last date this book was checked out",
    optional: true
  },
  summary: {
    type: String,
    label: "Brief summary",
    optional: true,
    max: 1000
  }
});

Books.attachSchema(Schemas.Book);

}
```

Can anyone give me any advice on this?

I'm thinking that I would need something *like* this:

```
Template.bookform.events({
'click btn.submit': function () {
  var form = document.getElementById("formID").value;
  Books.insert(form);
}
});
```

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have never used autoform but in the [documentation](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform#autoform) it says that it already gives you "automatic insert and update events, and automatic reactive validation".

So there should be no need to specify your own event handler.

In the [docs](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform#example) you will also find the books example. I am just copying from there:

JS

```
Books = new Meteor.Collection("books", {
    schema: {
        title: {
            type: String,
            label: "Title",
            max: 200
        },
        author: {
            type: String,
            label: "Author"
        },
        copies: {
            type: Number,
            label: "Number of copies",
            min: 0
        },
        lastCheckedOut: {
            type: Date,
            label: "Last date this book was checked out",
            optional: true
        },
        summary: {
            type: String,
            label: "Brief summary",
            optional: true,
            max: 1000
        }
    }
});

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Meteor.subscribe("books");
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.publish("books", function () {
    return Books.find();
  });
}
```

HTML

```
<head>
  <title>Book example</title>
</head>

<body>
  {{> insertBookForm}}
</body>

<template name="insertBookForm">
  {{> quickForm collection="Books" id="insertBookForm" type="insert"}}
</template>
```

Comment: Hi, yeah I've had a good look at the documentation.  The insert just doesn't seem to work.  I then had a look at the https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-collection2 package and that's where I picked up the insert function from.

Comment: I've updated my answer so the code is complete. Maybe you forgot to put the publish/subscribe code? But from your other question it seems you are using the autopublish package. Anyway, the code above should work. Can you please test exactly this code and report back?

Comment: That's perfect thank you.  I thought it would still work because I had the autopublish and insecure packages installed.

Books.find().fetch();
[Object { _id="BpjeYpbZzmYA7fe7J", title="title", author="author", more...}]

Comment: I would actually assume that it should work without the publish/subscribe logic if you are using the autopublish package. But if your problem is solved that's perfect!

Comment: Yeah that's it solved.  I'll look into the subscribe/publish features in more depth and see if I can get to grips with this a bit more.  Thanks again ....... next step to see if I can use autoform to add to the users profile, fingers crossed! :)